# htaccess <files> directive affecting subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess

The  directive in htaccess affects subdirectories as well, so:

```
<files login.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Is blocking access to all files named like that regardless of where they are located. Is there a way to make it apply only to the file in the current directory (where .htaccess is located) but not directories below it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Location instead of Files

```
<Location "path/folder/file">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod-rewrite` instead of `files` directive to deny access to a specific file.

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^login\.php$ - [R=403,L]
```

This will block access to a single URL `http://example.com/login.php` .

Or you can also use the following one liner mod-alias based blocking:

```
Redirect 403 /login.php
```